# Trigger when 'myLocation' button tapped (Google Maps SDK for iOS)

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to do some stuff when 'myLocation' button tapped.
So far, I've the `UIButton` itself:

```
UIButton *btnMyLoc = (UIButton*)[self.googleMapView subviews].lastObject;
```

But it's not enough.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In release 1.9.2 there is a delegate method that does exactly that:

```
(BOOL) didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView [optional]
```

[Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ac0e0171b811e839d9021800ca9fd33f4)

Answer (score 2):

Delegate method available

```
func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no direct method in Google Maps IOS sdk for knowing when the user taps on **MyLocation button**. A possible workaround is to use the below method

```
- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView  idleAtCameraPosition: (GMSCameraPosition *)   position
```

This will be called at the end of any camera animation or gestures. When a user clicks mylocation button, the camera will be animated to position the visible map region such that the user's current location(if detected) will lie at the center. So you can check inside **idleAtCameraPosition** whether the location is same as the user's current location that can be known through `- (CLLocation*) myLocation [read, assign]` and do your required functionality.

Comment: to make sure this work, we need to add `<GMSMapViewDelegate>` as a delegate for our class.

Answer (score 0):

For do any thing other you also can get reference to Location Button.

```
// custom target My Location Button
    for (UIView* tmpview in _mapView.subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([[tmpview class] class]) isEqualToString:@"GMSx_QTMButton"]) {
            if ([tmpview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                myLocationBtn = (UIButton*)tmpview;
                [myLocationBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedOnLocationButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {


//if want to change the camera position

            if self.latDouble != 0.0 && self.longDouble != 0.0
            {
                let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.latDouble, longitude: self.longDouble, zoom: 18.0)
                self.mapView.camera = camera

            }

             self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            self.mapView.reloadInputViews()
            return true
        }
```